# Sliding from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slide

I am trying to slide a a panel from the right of the button to the left. Here is my css:

style.css:

```
.pToolContainer {
    position : absolute;
    right: 0;
}
.btn-pTool{
    //display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-image: url(slide_button.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.btn-pToolName{
    text-align: center; 
    width: 26px; 
    height: 190px; 
    display: block; 
    color: #fff; 
    text-decoration: none;  
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 1em; 
    line-height: 32px; 
}
.pToolSlidePanel{
    min-height: 185px;
    min-width: 185px; /*WIDTH OF HIDDEN SLIDE PANEL*/ 
    display: none; /*THE ELEMENT WILL NOT BE DISPLAYED*/ 
    border-right-width: 2px; /*ADDS RIGHT BORDER OF 2PX*/ 
    border-left-width: 2px; /*ADDS LEFT BORDER OF 2PK*/ 
    border-right-style: solid; /*MAKES RIGHT BORDER SOLID*/ 
    border-left-style: solid; /*MAKES LEFT BORDER SOLID*/ 
    border-right-color: #626262; /*RIGHT BORDER COLOR*/ 
    border-left-color: #626262; /*LEFT BORDER COLOR*/ 
    background-color: #949494; /*SLIDE PANEL BACKGROUND COLOR*/ 
    border-bottom-width: 2px; /*ADDS BOTTOM BORDER OF 2PX*/ 
    border-bottom-style: solid; /*MAKES BOTTOM BORDER SOLID*/ 
    border-bottom-color: #626262;
    border-top-width: 2px; /*ADDS BOTTOM BORDER OF 2PX*/ 
    border-top-style: solid; /*MAKES BOTTOM BORDER SOLID*/ 
    border-top-color: #626262; /*BOTTOM BORDER COLOR*/ 
    opacity: .8; /*SETS SLIDE PANEL BACKGROUND'S OPACITY TO 80%*/ 
    margin: auto; /*CENTERS OUR SLIDE PANEL*/ 
    position: fixed;
    //bottom: 50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

test.html:

```
<div class="pToolContainer">
     <span class="btn-pTool">
         <a class="btn-pToolName" href="#"></a>
     </span>
     <div class="pToolSlidePanel"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following jquery statement but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$(pToolSlidePanel).animate({width:'toggle'},2000);
```

where pToolSlidePanel is the HTMLElement created in my javascript file using:

var pToolSlidePanel = document.createElement("div");

I have also tried the following tutorial http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions but I keep getting an error stating that HTMLElement does not have a css method

Comment: I updated my answer below with a working example.

Answer (score 2):

> - **DEMO:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/sliding-from-right-to-left/

```
        $(function() {
            var iXS = 3, $slider = $('.panel-inner'), liW = $slider.find('li:first').width(), liFW = parseInt(liW * $slider.find('li').length);
            $slider.css('width', liFW + 'px');
            $('.button a').click(function() {
                var left = (this.id == 'right') ? parseInt($slider.css('left').toString().replace('-', '')) : parseInt($slider.css('left'));
                var side = (this.id == 'right') ? (((left + (liW * iXS)) == liFW) ? 0 : -(left + liW)) : ((left < 0) ? -(parseInt(left.toString().replace('-', '')) - liW) : 0);
                rotate(side);
                return false;
            });
            var rotate = function(leftY) {
                $slider.stop(true, true).animate({
                    left : leftY
                }, 500);
            }
        });
```

for full code look at the source code of demo example.

Answer (score 1):

**Try** this

```
$(".pToolSlidePanel").animate({width:'toggle'},2000);
```

For Class **pToolSlidePanel** use `$(".pToolSlidePanel")`

and For eg: id **pToolSlidePanel** use `$("#pToolSlidePanel")`

Comment: well pToolSlidePanel is already a HTMLElement so it doesn't really matter if I put "." infront of it or not. I have create pToolSlidePanel using : var pToolSLidePanel = document.createElement("p")...

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Try this configuration here** http://jsfiddle.net/TQZh5/50/

I removed some of the CSS to make it easier, but it should be trivial to add it back in.

```
$(pToolSlidePanel).animate({width:'toggle'},2000);
```

Should be

`$('.pToolSlidePanel').animate({width:'toggle'},2000)`;

Also, what are you binding the animate action to? Is the jQuery wrapped in the ready() function so it knows the DOM is completely loaded?

Comment: well the jquery is wrapped inside a function which is loaded in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

Want to slide a element from position A(right) to B(left)?

HTML:

```
<div class="pToolContainer">
    <div class="pToolSlidePanel">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pToolContainer {
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    position:relative;
}
.pToolSlidePanel
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#ffcc33;
}
```

Javascript (jQuery):

```
$('.pToolSlidePanel').animate({
    left: '-=200'
  }, 2000);
```